# codeigniter doest play a video in it even tho every thing is correct

Tags: codeigniter

am trying to play a video on my Codeigniter web project but when I use the video tag it just displays the controls and doesn't play the video

this the view

```
<h3><?php echo $video['title']; ?></h3>
```

Posted on:

```
<div class="col-md-3">

    <!--div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"-->

    <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="300" height="300" controls data-setup='{}'>

    <source src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $video['video']; ?>" type='video/mp4'>
```

```
<!--/div-->
```

I want it to play a video  from the above source in my web page

Comment: You need to share your controller code so we can see exactly how you are populating the `$video` variable and passing it to the view

Comment: okclass Media extends CI_Controller
 {
  
   public function index()
   {
   
   $data['title'] = 'Media Post';
   $data['videos'] = $this->media_model->get_videos();
   

   $this->load->view('includes/header');
   $this->load->view('media/index', $data);
   $this->load->view('includes/footer');
  }

Comment: kay am new around here how do i send you the controllers code

Comment: you need to edit your question, please don't put your updates/edits as comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one.**
**If there's still error, please let us know.**

**Thanks**

**Controller**

```
class Media extends CI_Controller { 
    public function index() { 
        $data['title'] = 'Media Post'; 
        $data['videos'] = $this->media_model->get_videos(); 
        $this->load->view('includes/header'); 
        $this->load->view('media/index', $data); 
        $this->load->view('includes/footer'); 
    }
}
```

**In Views**

```
<div class="col-md-3">

<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="300" 
height="300" controls>
    <source src="<?= site_url().$videos->video; ?>" 
    type="video/mp4">
</video>

</div>
```

Comment: no it didnt work it only displays this   http://localhost:/test/upload/" type="video/mp4"> under the video controller

Comment: if you show your controller, model, & view then I can solve the issue.
Please provide these.
Thanks

Comment: okay i will show but  how may i send you my model ,view and controller  plus am new around here